# Как выполняется кастомизация?

Tags: java, android

Я разбираюсь с примером в котором применяется кастомный `SeekBar`, я хочу посмотреть как выполняется эта кастомизация, но в проекте нет ни намека на кастомизацию, такое впечатление, что используется стандартный `SeekBar`.

**Вот слайд как `SeekBar` выглядит в превью**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот слайд как он выглядит на самом деле**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот код XML**

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/total_time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_time"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:progress="0"
        android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

Я думал, может в самом `MainActivity` добавлен `background` либо `style`, но там нет ничего кроме `listener` и еще пары функций типо `setProgress` `setSecondaryProgress`.

Манифест выглядит так

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.adw.samples.discreteseekbar">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="org.adw.samples.discreteseekbar.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Кто может объяснить каким образом получается такой красивый `SeekBar`?

Comment: на первом скриншоте бар из темы Holo (android 4), на втором из android 2.3 - это зависит от указанной в манифесте темы для приложения.

Comment: @pavlofff добавил манифест на, что в нем нужно обратить внимание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать свой SeekBar, например, таким способом:

```
<SeekBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

thumb.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/myColor" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000" />
    <size android:width="18dp"
        android:height="18dp"/>
</shape>
```

progress.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <corners android:radius="5dp" />
     <solid android:color="@color/progressBack" />
</shape>
```